# Where can I order a 36 foot by 18 foot canvas print?

Tags: print-design

I have an illustrator vector artwork which I would like printed onto a 36x18 foot canvas.  None of the online canvas websites support anything near this size.  What are my options?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a shopping question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one (that I am aware of) can print a canvas that big on one piece.

The canvas is not that big. They might print it on pieces and stitch them together, but probably they do not take responsibility because they need to fold it and this will damage the canvas.

You might consider to print it in rows or smaller squares and stitch them yourself. But stitching is a tricky process, sometimes pieces do not match perfectly.